# zsh sed distinguish "\(" from "("

Tags: macos, sed, zsh, slash

I'm doing some string editing from a zsh script (on Mac OS Catalina). Some of the strings have a parentheses with a slash before and some don't (usually a space before).

I'm trying to write a command that ignores a left parenthesis unless it has a slash beforehand.

So the command...

```
sed 's/"\("/"\\\("/g'
```

...would not be triggered by...

```
"foo (bar)"
```

...but would be triggered on...

```
"foo \(bar)"
```

Comment: Try `sed 's/\\*(/\\(/g'`

Comment: That's not working as expected, let me play around with a bit more. I wanted the output to be "\\\("

Comment: And what is expected? If you need double ``\`` use `sed 's/\\*(/\\\\(/g'`

Comment: it's not letting me post here, but I wanted 2 slashes and a parenthesis as the output

Comment: that works.....

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `zsh`, but simply with the regular expression you are trying to use with `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/\\*(/\\\\(/g' file > outfile
```

Here, `\\*(` matches any amount of `\` and then `(` and the `\\\\(` replacement actually replaces with two `\` chars and then `(`. It is necessary to use double backslash in the replacement part to represent one backslash because `\` is used to encode backreferences (like `\1`, `\2`, etc.).